# Int array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have this int array:

```
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
etc
```

What I need to do is to make a function that gives me an array that is something like this

```
0,1
0,2
0,3
0,4
```

It returns all the results that have the same number in the index 0.
And the next time I call it, it should return:

```
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
```

And so on. Or it can also return this

```
0,1,2,3,4
1,5,6,7,8
```

and so on

Help please :(

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of your int array, too? is it something like  Dim variable(,) as integer?

Comment: Yes It's Dim variable(,) as Integer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have something like

```
Dim variable(,) as Integer '(2-dimensional array)
```

then you can use a simple loop for that:

```
Dim _result as New List(Of String)
For i as Integer = 0 to 1
  For j as Integer = 1 to 4
    _result.Add(variable(i, j+i*4).ToString)
  Next j
  _result.Add(vbCrLf)
Next i
MsgBox(Join(_result.ToArray,","))
```

It is a bit dirty, would be better to combine each line and do another join with vbCrLf, because this way you have another comma in front of every additional line, but it should be sufficient to understand how it works.

**Updated**
Well, I doubt that you need those places from the array, but not the answer fits to it. 4 Elements, so the second array can just be accessed with 1 to 4 plus 4 * first array index

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fantastic, but you may also want to try this using more 'modern' objects like Dictionaries and Lists

Try this:

```
' Load the data
Dim x As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))
x.Add(1, New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3, 4}))
x.Add(2, New List(Of Integer)({5, 6, 7, 8}))


' Access the data
Debug.Print("items under 1")
For Each i As Integer In x.Item(1)
    Debug.Print(i)
Next

Debug.Print("items under 2")
For Each i As Integer In x.Item(2)
    Debug.Print(i)
Next
```

This gives output like:

```
items under 1
1
2
3
4
items under 2
5
6
7
8
```